# Permission for destination upload folder in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions

I am confused !!!
destination folder is `'/uploads'`.
I can not upload file with PHP to `'/uploads'` when permission for this folder is `0755` and this error displayed `Unable to write in the "/uploads" directory'` 
before script upload I check for username linux by `get_current_user()` PHP function and that display `string(4) root` .this mean I logged in by root user and get uploaded file with root user and want to save uploaded with root user.so why permission error occurs ??
when change permission for `'/uploads'` to `'0757'` no error display and upload successfully .but I don't want to change permission to `'0757'` .because that mean other can write to the `'/uploads'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which user is your HTTP server running as? Typically it will be something like "www-data". Change the ownership of your uploads folder to "www-data:www-data" and you should be able to save data in there.

Comment: I use get_current_user() php function in my script and that display root.this does not mean that current user is root ??

Comment: Nope. Just tested it myself. Try `print_r( posix_getpwuid( posix_geteuid() ) );`

Comment: Then your user is apache. `chown -R apache:apache ./uploads; chmod -R 755 ./uploads`